# interface builder view ui design changing in landscape mode ios

Tags: ios, iphone

i have created universal app and all view controller xib's designed for iPhone(320x460), but when it rotates to landscape the ui design totally changed, please anyone let me know how to design for landscape and same as ipad also.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also suggest you learning Autolayout for configuring same view for different orientations and devices but only when the design is really complex and cant be solved using the `Spring and Struts` Model. `Autolayout` sometimes is a real pain.

If your design is simple, you can sort out many of your views simply using the Spring and Struts model(Autoresizing) and you don't need `Autolayout` or drawing separate Stroyboard files and nibs.

Comment: Thanks but i need some more clear, please let me know what is spring and stats and how to use those

Comment: Just look at this tutorial:http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2. It explains both Autolayout and Spring and Stuts Model of Autoresizing. After going through this, you may have clear idea what you need to support in your app.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to support both orientations and platforms (iPhone & iPad) is to use AutoLayout. Here's a good introduction on Apple Developer [website](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> Auto Layout is a system that lets you lay out your app’s user interface by creating a mathematical description of the relationships between the elements. You define these relationships in terms of constraints either on individual elements, or between sets of elements. Using Auto Layout, you can create a dynamic and versatile interface that responds appropriately to changes in screen size, device orientation, and localisation.

Also, check out WWDC sessions on AutoLayout.

Comment: Always glad to help. If this appears as a correct answer, feel free to mark it so.